# How to get day of the week from the selected date on datepicker using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

How do I get day of the week from the selected date on datepicker and if selected date day is saturday or sunday show `openstatus1` else show `openstatus`.

*JavaScript*

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
        autoclose: true, 
        todayHighlight: true
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    if(e.date && e.date.GetDay()==6 && e.date.GetDay()==7) {
        $('.openstatus').toggle();
    } else {
        $('.openstatus1').toggle();
    }
});
```

*My form*

```
<div id="datepicker" class="input-group" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
<input class="form-control" name="Date" type="text" readonly />
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="openstatus">

    <select name="ResTime" class=" selectpicker">
        <option  selected="selected" value="select time">Select Time</option>
        <option value="10:30am">10:30 am</option>
        <option value="11:00am">11:00 am</option>
        <option value="11:30am">11:30 am</option>
        <option value="12:00pm">12:00 pm</option>
        <option value="12:30pm">12:30 pm</option>
        <option value="1:00pm">1:00 pm</option>
        <option value="1:30pm">1:30 pm</option>
        <option value="2:00pm">2:00 pm</option>
        <option value="2:30pm">2:30 pm</option>
        <option value="3:00pm">3:00 pm</option>
        <option value="3:30pm">3:30 pm</option>
        <option value="4:00pm">4:00 pm</option>
        <option value="4:30pm">4:30 pm</option>
        <option value="5:00pm">5:00 pm</option>  
    </select>

</div>
<div class="openstatus1">

    <select name="ResTime" class="selectpicker">
        <option  selected="selected" value="select time">Select Time</option>
        <option value="8:00am">8:00 am</option>
        <option value="8:30am">8:30 am</option>
        <option value="9:00am">9:00 am</option>
        <option value="9:30am">9:30 am</option>
        <option value="10:00am">10:00 am</option>
        <option value="10:30am">10:30 am</option>
        <option value="11:00am">11:00 am</option>
        <option value="11:30am">11:30 am</option>
        <option value="12:00pm">12:00 pm</option>
        <option value="12:30pm">12:30 pm</option>   
    </select>

</div>
```

Comment: What the problem with your code? I see that you already check this//

Comment: @MoshFeu my code is not working it does not hide the div **openstatus** and show **openstatus1**

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, GetDay() for sunday is 0, not 7.

> The getDay() method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where 0 represents Sunday.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

You're also checking if a value == 6 *and* == 7, which it won't ever, so you need to change the to *or*

So your code should be:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    autoclose: true, 
    todayHighlight: true
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    if(e.date && (e.date.GetDay() == 6 || e.date.GetDay() == 0)) {
        $('.openstatus').toggle();
    } else {
        $('.openstatus1').toggle();
    }
});
```

---

The next issue you'll find is that `.toggle()` will only toggle the items you select.  You can use toggle with a boolean flag, but sometimes it's clearer to be explicit so show/hide what you want, giving:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    autoclose: true, 
    todayHighlight: true
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    if(e.date && (e.date.GetDay() == 6 || e.date.GetDay() == 0)) {

        // show hide .openstatus/.openstatus1 as required (ie might need to swap these two)
        $('.openstatus').show();
        $('.openstatus1').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.openstatus').hide();
        $('.openstatus1').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: ok I see your solution but but now my datepicker field is becoming black it does not show any calendar.

Comment: This question was about getting the day of week (and not really about the datepicker).  You might like to open a new question and provide a working [mcve].

Comment: Ok but my datepicker field changed after adding your suggested code. Thanks any way.